# Long levelup query

Tags: node.js, express, leveldb

I have this express route...

```
app.get('/:grp/:time', function(req, res){
  var out = [];
  var grp = grpmap[req.param('grp')];
  var time = timemap[req.param('time')];
  leveldb.createReadStream({start:'HEM!' + grp + '!' + time + '!', end:'HEM!' + grp + '!' + time + '!\xff', keys: false})
    .on('data',function(data){
      out.push(JSON.parse(data));
    })
    .on('close',function(){
      res.send(out);
    })
});
```

It works as expected, but it takes along time to populate out, the client sits for several seconds before receiving a response.  There has to be a better way..any hints?

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

This takes a long time because you're buffering the entire set of results before sending anything.

What you want to do is stream the data instead of buffering. You'll want to use a module like [JSONStream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/JSONStream) like this:

```
var JSONStream = require('JSONStream')

app.get('/route', function (req, res) {
  db.createReadStream({...}).pipe(JSONStream.stringify()).pipe(res);
})
```

The entire request may take the same amount of time, but you should start receiving data very quickly since this does not wait until all results have been buffered before sending anything.